# Can't get up with RIA demo

Tags: wcf, silverlight, service

Based the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/17/mix09-building-amazing-business-applications-with-silverlight-3.aspx)  I've tried to start-up the RIA services.

At the moment there are 2 blockers:

1. On the client side I don't have
   `<datagrid:DataGrid` component. Does
   anybody know what namespace contains
   this object?  (already resolved with
   Silverlight Toolkit usage, thanks to
   Refracted Paladin for help)
2. On the
   client side I don't have access to
   my DomainService... don't know why. Also, I con't see "System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client" assembly available to be added to the projects references.

Could anybody help to resolve the 2nd problem?

Thank you.

P.S. I have VS2008, SP1, Silverlight, RIA Services installed.

Comment: For the missing DataGrid, how about the Silverlight toolkit?  http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight

Comment: Paladin, thank you. Totally missed the Toolkit. Get the datagrid :)

P.S. Why you didn't create an "answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess, the problem was in some mistery (my machine has different issues last few days). As a results my ReSharper wasn't able to find the class in a namespace that was not mentioned in the "using" section.

At the moment domain service is accessible on the client side of my Silverlight app. I clicked "Show All Files" for the Silverlight project and found 'Generated_Code' folder that contained all required generated files. In that file full class name is specified, I've used it in my pages and all is workable now.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client is part of the RIA Services RC for SL4/VS2010.  The DLL's for RIA Services RTW for SL3/VS2008 are completely different.  And to my knowledge, they can't be installed side-by-side - I have tried.

This article points out some of the differences between the 2 versions, and how to move to RIA Services for SL4/VS2010: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/03/15/contososales-mix10.aspx

If you do end up installing RIA Services for SL4/VS2010, you access the "System.ServiceModel.DomainServices" namespace with a reference to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Silverlight\System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll".

Comment: Jim, Thanks for comment. I am using VS2008 and RIA Services for SL3, so this DomainServices assembly is not for me.